# How do I configure nginx to have one http page on a mostly https site?

Tags: nginx, local-storage

I recently moved my pure-client-side site from `http` to `https`, and users now have a new localStorage for the `https://...` site. I don't have user IDs, and didn't think it was worth implementing them to store the http storage info on the server. But I read on how I could create an `http` hidden iframe on the `https` page and use its info to migrate the `http` localStorage to the new `https` page.

I tried this config, but everything is still coming up as `https`:

```
   server {
     server_name example.com www.example.com localhost;
     listen 80;
     listen [::]:80;

     location / {
         if ($request_uri = "/http-stats.html") {
            return 200 http://$host$request_uri;
         }
         return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
     }
  }
…
```

I don't see a `not` directive in the nginx docs. Is there a reasonable way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to have Nginx listening on both port 80 (HTTP) and
port 443 (HTTPS).

This is the accepted answer in the post
[Nginx server with both HTTP and HTTPS, browser selecting HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33279099/nginx-server-with-both-http-and-https-browser-selecting-http):

Turns out it is possible to have both HTTP and HTTPS servers and choose HTTPS by default. I just had to mix the two servers of the conf file in one, just like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 default_server ssl;

    ssl_certificate certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key server.key;

    server_name server.com;
    server_name *.server.com;
    client_max_body_size 0;
    charset utf-8;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Except I wanted my site to redirect to https because I was getting screenshots from users with an insecure-site warning. It's a daily game with no registration or PII, but http sites are deprecated these days and I'm trying to stay up to date.

Comment: Thinking about it, the main site is at the index page of /index.html, so I suppose I can just redirect that one, right? Like redirect `= /` and `/index.html` to https and leave everything else as http ? I'll give that a try.